# Is this form of cloaking likely to be penalised? 

Tags: javascript, asp.net, seo

I'm looking to create a website which is considerably javascript heavy, built with backbone.js and most content being passed as JSON and loaded via backbone. I just needed some advice or opinions on likely hood of my website being penalised using the method of serving plain HTML (text, images, everything) to search engine bots and an js front-end version to normal users.

**This is my basic plan for my site:**

I plan on having the first request to any page being html which will only give about 1/4 of the page and there after load the last 3/4 with backbone js. Therefore non javascript users get a 'bit' of the experience.

Once that new user has visited and detected to have js will have a cookie saved on their machine and requests from there after will be AJAX only. Example

```
If (AJAX || HasJSCookie) {
     // Pass JSON 
}
```

**Search Engine server content:**

That entire experience of loading via AJAX will be stripped if a google bot for example is detected, the same content will be servered but all html.

I thought about just allowing search engines to index the first 1/4 of content but as I'm considered about inner links and picking up every bit of content I thought it would be better to give search engines the entire content.

I plan to do this by just detected a list of user agents and knowing if it's a bot or not.

```
If (Bot) {
    //server plain html
}
```

In addition I plan to make clean URLs for the entire website despite full AJAX, therefore providing AJAX content to www.example.com/#/page and normal html to www.example.com/page is kind of our of the question. Would rather avoid the practice of using # when there are technology such as HTML 5 push state is around.

So my question is really just asking the opinion of the masses on if it's likely that my website will be penalised?

And do you suggest an alternative which avoids 'noscript' method

Answer (score 1):

As long as the content is the same this is perfectly fine as cloaking is only an issue when it's used to serve the search engines different content for the purpose of manipulating your rankings.

However, you're doing it wrong. You shouldn't be looking for search engine bots to serve up static content, you should be serving up static content to *everybody* who doesn't use JavaScript. It's called [progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement). You should be assuming that every visitor who visits your website doesn't support JavaScript. Then, if they do, enhance their experience by using JavaScript to dynamically deliver content.

Comment: I kept progressive enhancement in mind, but I was avoiding having any excess content attached to the initial page load, obviously to speed up the page load and do it purely with js. With this method my only concern was search engines indexing my content as a user without js is rare in itself. But in the end I went for the progressive enhancement route, just making it easier overall and avoid any possible penalising, and covering every possible user, even the rare. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Google actually offers a mechanism for this.  Check it out here: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started

The idea is that you can continue to offer up AJAX "injected" content on your site, but you are essentially providing a means for Google to also get at it and an API of sorts to let them know how to get it.

John Conde is very right, but I think even Google realises that Javascript is becoming essential on the web and they are introducing a means of indexing injected content.

Comment: but only google can browse these URLs and not non-javascript users.

Comment: Thanks for voicing your concern.  However, I don't think that the OP was interested in access for non-JS users, he/she was interested in how to make it easier for Google to index their content, serving alternate content for the Google Bot if require.  Since it is not 100% clear to anyone but Google what techniques will penalize the website in making alternate content just for Google, and Google has published these specs, it is pretty fair to say, this is how Google wants it to be done.

Comment: Thank you for your response, its true non-JavaScript users weren't my biggest concern as there are not many. But I did consider the hash bang method but I felt it have too many drawbacks such as the loss of clean URLs and I believe only Google can index these URLs. I've taken the progressive enhancement route where JavaScript will enhance the functionality of the webpage but I have also included HTML 5 push state, for the people with HTML 5 browsers can then experience a richer user experience, and lesser browsers will navigate through pages as normal and still have other JS functionality.

Answer (score -1):

its much much better If you can include a link (even small one)
or maybe one in your site map (preffered way) to the html version
instead of using a redirect meant only for the bot....

**Personally i think...**
The only reason to deal with the bot is a mobile version of your website.